# Android Google Map with Multiple Poly-line with different colors

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I want to display multiple routes at the same time in google map in such a way that each route should be separate(e.g. Route1 A-B-C in Green Color and Route2 D-E-F-G in Blue Color.... could be number of routes(Limited)) and for that I was trying to implement multiple poly-line with different color. I have faced some issues...

1. Routes are not separated.
2. Displaying in color which I am giving for the last route.

[Image for requirement with 2 poly-line... but there could be n number of poly-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yetSZ.png)

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same like this:

```
GoogleMap map;
   // ... get a map.

map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(75.5, -1.1), new LatLng(60.7, -84.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: map.addPolyline(line1); Method doesn't exist. Its asking to pass PolylineOption instead of polyline.

Comment: Use this:    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

// Create polyline options with existing LatLng ArrayList
polylineOptions.add(yourLatLong);
polylineOptions
 .width(5)
 .color(Color.RED);